# No Tile Palette option available in Unity editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

The [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-Palette.html) clearly shows Tile Palette available under Window > 2D.

[image]

But I don't have the option available:

[image]

Where can I access the Tile Palette menu?

I'm on OSX 10.13.6 and Unity version 2019.2.1f1

Comment: Judging from the UI style, are you using IOS? The option is there on windows in 2019.1.8. So it might be a bug with IOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2020/08/03**
The issue is fixed in Unity 2019.3 and beyond, where the tile palette option shows up as expected on iOS, making it likely the issue was caused by a bug in 2019.2

---

As per AJP's own findings: Tile Palette is not available on Mac OSX. But if it was this would be a work around for *any* menu not showing up in the toolbar.

---

(I could only test this on windows, but I assume this works on a mac aswel, under the same locations.)

Under Edit there is the option "shortcuts". Go into this window and search for "Tile pallete". Click the Tile palette command and set your custom shortcut. You should now be able to open it without it showing up under the Window > 2D tab.

If it doesn't show up there either then my only guess would be that it isn't installed in your current Unity version (which appears to be the case on mac OSX)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @remy_rm , that's a great idea.  Unfortunately it looks like `Tile Palette` is not available on Mac OSX Unity.  Thanks though.  I will mark your answer as correct even though it can't fix the issue.  Could you add a comment at the top saying "Tile Palette is not available on Mac OSX.  But if it was..." ;)

Answer (score 30):

@AJP I was just having a similar issue using 2019.2 Personal.

I found that I needed to add the tile map package to the project, then "Tile Palette" appeared as an option under "Window".

To do this:

1. Go to Window > Package Manager.
2. Click 2d Tilemap Editor on the left of the pop up.
3. Then click install in the lower right hand corner (Install will be replaced with "Remove" once installed).

[2dTileMapPackage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfOTf.png)

Comment: Are you on a Mac @mperic @Jere?  If so I'll mark this as correct (I haven't tried it out myself)

Comment: @AJP I am not. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: This ended up solving a similar problem I had. I didn't see an option to create a "tile" asset and it turned out the tile map editor wasn't installed. Worth noting for anyone else trying to install the tilemap editor Package: make sure the filters at the top of the Package Manager are set to "Packages: Unity Registry". That filter was set to "In Project" for me and was hiding everything that wasn't already installed. User error!

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me and no solution is working please READ THIS!

The problem is with Unity Hub and not Unity as a whole. I discovered this late late last night when I was reinstalling for the 5th time.

On my 5th install and reboot, I opened "Unity" instead of "Unity Hub" and sure enough there it was. I closed "Unity" and opened "Unity Hub" and sure enough when I booted into "Unity" it was gone. There is something wrong with the back end loading it would seem when loading from Unity Hub.

For a problem that seems to have plagued people for years. I'm shocked Unity developers haven't come across this solution and patched it.

Comment: That was the one worked only for me. Unity version is 2019.4

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install the according package like RobC and Jere already mentioned..

It's the same if you miss Sprite Editor.

You just have to install the according package which in your case is **2D Tilemap Editor**

`Window > Package Manager` search for the according package,
in this case `2D Tilemap Editor`.

If you miss the Sprite Editor the package to install is:
-"2D Sprite", I guess